# rename a table with dependencies in db2

Tags: db2

I wanna alter a table name in db2

```
rename table X to Y;
```

But this table has dependencies so I get this error:

```
DB2 SQL Error:SQLCODE=-750, SQLSTATE=42986, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.57.82
```

How can I rename this table?

Answer (score 3):

You can rename the table with the admin_mov_table stored procedure.

Here the information: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055069.html

```
call SYSPROC.ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE ('myschema', 'X', 'Y', '', 'MOVE');
```

Answer (score 2):

Run a `db2look` on that table to obtain all references, and backup this DDL.

Delete all constraints, and drop all triggers referencing the table

Rename your table

Use the DDL, change it to point to the new table name, and recreate the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons could lead to this errors :

First of them was the created index of the table you try to rename. Delete the index and rename the table :

```
RENAME TABLE YourSchemaName.OldtableName TO NewTableName;
```

and create the index again.

Another reason is the objects (views, stored procedure and foreign keys). This request show you which object is linked to your table which you want to rename :

```
select * 
from SYSCAT.TABDEP t
where t.BSCHEMA = 'YourSchemaName'
  and t.BNAME = 'YourTableName';
```